# How to make the WP-Shopify only work on certain pages

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shopify

I wondered if someone could help me with editing the wpshopify/wp-shopify.php in WordPress.
My goal is to make the Shopify plugin work on certain pages and not run on other pages.
So for example I would like the plugin to work on the `[shop]` page and not the `[about us]` page.
I have seen some "Plugin Organizers" but unfortunately I couldn't make it work.

Does anyone have the experience or know-how to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage the styles and JavaScript of a plugin in WordPress so that on any page you just want to be loaded and used, I suggest using the following plugins.

- WordPress Assets manager, dequeue scripts, dequeue styles
- gonzales wp
- Deactivate Plugins Per Page

But if you want to write a condition that you can manage, it means a specific plugin only when you want it to work like a specific page. For this you need to know the exact name of the plugin and then do it using a plugin management function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Morteza . However, I don't want to use "Plugin Organizers" because every time I install a new plugin or delete an old plugin...it becomes a mess.

All I want is to edit the `wpshopify` plugin to work on a specific page. I thought that someone would know how to achieve this (again) whiteout using another plugin.

Comment: you're welcome @CrossProduction
You can give me the exact address of the plugin you are using
I found these two
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-shopify/
And
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpshopify/
Which do you use?
So that I can write a code for you that you can use only on certain pages without installing another plugin

Comment: Hi @Morteza, Thanks again for your quick response. To answer your question. I have the plugin of the following website [www.wpshop.io/](https://wpshop.io/)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code and tested it, it worked properly.

In this code, I first check the post ID, whether page or post or any other type of post.

Then I disable all plugin styles and scripts and delete the class that is attached to the body

Finally, I remove a new element created in a class to display the plugin root.

Put this code in the `functions.php` file

```
function disble_shopwp_pages()
{


    $post_id_array = array(
        218, 433, 71, 2066, 825, 7, 2009, 2284, 420, 2402, 2394,
    );

    if (in_array(get_the_ID(), $post_id_array)) {

        return true;
    }


}

function remove_wpshopify()
{


    if (disble_shopwp_pages()):

        wp_dequeue_style('shopwp-styles-frontend-all');
        wp_deregister_style('shopwp-styles-frontend-all');
        wp_dequeue_script('shopwp-runtime');
        wp_dequeue_script('shopwp-vendors-public');
        wp_dequeue_script('shopwp-public');


    endif;
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_wpshopify', 9999);


function wpshopify_body_class($classes)
{

    if (disble_shopwp_pages()) {
        unset($classes[array_search('shopwp', $classes)]);
    }

    return $classes;
}

add_filter('body_class', 'wpshopify_body_class', 999, 2);

function remove_shopwp_root_elements()
{


    if (disble_shopwp_pages()) {

        echo '<script>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                            jQuery("#shopwp-root").remove();
                    });
                  </script>';

    }
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'remove_shopwp_root_elements');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the code doesn't seem to work. I guess Shopify doesn't want anybody to change anything.

Comment: I ran a site on the local with exactly the same plugin and
I did the test with the same codes I wrote
Everything worked fine.
And Shapifa did not work exactly on the pages I specified

Comment: Enter the ID of the page you want to disable
Put $ ID in the disble_shopwp_pages function.
Have you done this?

Comment: Hi @Morteza

I have used it as follows `if (in_array(get_the_ID(), $218, $433, $71, $2066, $825, $7, $2009, $420)) {` However, I cant make it work. Maybe I am missing something

I get the following:
`syntax error, unexpected '218' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'`

Comment: @CrossProduction Hello
First, variables cannot be named with numbers.

And second, they do not have to be variables, just write their number or do it like me


    $post_id_array = array(
        218, 433, 71, 2066, 825, 825, 7, 2009, 420
    );

    if (in_array(get_the_ID(), $post_id_array)) {

        return true;
    }

Comment: I rewrite my answer
Check it out

Comment: Dear @morteza-barati If I go to the `Plugin Editor` and paste your code in file `\wpshopify\classes\compatibility\temp-theme\functions.php` it still doesn't work for me. I think I am pasting the code in the wrong file. Could you inform me where exactly I should paste this code? With kind regards <3